# Laravel and AJAX 405 (Method Not Allowed) work on one page only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have **Note function** this note function allow the user to create not from **any route** in the web app.

> JQuery Code

```
//CREATE NOTE BUTTON
$('#createNoteButton').click(function () {
    var title = $('#getNoteTitle').val();
    var body  = $('#getNoteBody').val();
    var users = $('#getNoteUsers').val();
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    var data  = {
        _token:     CSRF_TOKEN,
        title:      title,
        body:       body,
        users:      users
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'note-create',
        data: data,
        success:function(data){
            if(data == 1)
                location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

> NotesController.php

```
public function create(Request $request){
        $logged_user_id     = Auth::user() -> id;
        $logged_user_name   = Auth::user() -> name;
        $note = new Note;
        $note -> title      = $request -> title;
        $note -> body       = $request -> body;
        $note -> owner_name = $logged_user_name;
        $note -> owner_id   = $logged_user_id;
        $note -> save();
        $users = $request -> users;
        if($users != '')
            array_push($users, $logged_user_id);
        else
            $users = [$logged_user_id];

        $note -> users() -> attach($users);

        return '1';
    }
```

> Route Code

```
Route::post('note-create',         'NotesController@create');
```

> Problem

Everything works perfectly but only in the home page **route('/')** and any other route I get this error message `405 (Method Not Allowed)`.

> What I have tried

I tried to check the url in the route and in the ajax request and both is right I think

Comment: I would normally use a slash before `url:'note-create'`, i.e `url:'/note-create'` in the JQuery. I am not sure if this is a problem though...just a suggestion

Comment: omg! i got an syntax error and you are right its my bad i need to write `url:'/note-create'` thanks!

Comment: is this issue fixed now?

Answer (score 0):

The OP's question is answered but for further explanation for others:

The url you are creating is relative. It is working from home '/' but it'll be making a relative url from other pages, and hence failing.

www.mySite.com/note-create *<- works*

www.mySite.com/blog/note-create *<- doesn't work as this is not the correct route*

You can insert the correct url from any Laravel blade page that will work from any route like so:

```
<script>
   var url = "{{url('/note-create')}}";

   ...
</script>
```

See the Laravel docs for more url goodness: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls